# How to avoid using IPv6 `::1` when sending a syslog message via `logger` to `localhost`

Tags: networking, ipv6, logging, ipv4

When using `logger -n localhost -port 12345 ...` I realized that logger is using IPv6 when creating the socket.
Unfortunately my syslog server listens on IPv4 only.

The work-around I found was to use the local host name instead of `localhost`; then IPv4 is used to send the message.
The OS is SLES12 SP5, and `logger` is from `util-linux-systemd-2.33.2-4.11.1.x86_64`.

Is there another way to make `logger` use IPv4 when using `localhost`?

`/etc/hosts` contains these lines for `localhost`:

```text
127.0.0.1  localhost
::1        localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback
```

Comment: what if you use 127.0.0.1? the ipv4 adress of local host?

Comment: And also, what if you ommit localhost alltogether? as far as I can tell, logger should try local by default anyway.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/hosts`? That's the most likely culprit here.

Comment: @LPChip On leaving out the host: It would connect to the standard syslogd, but that is not what I want: I have an additional alternate syslogd that uses a different port to listen to (under development) that I want to address.

Comment: Using `127.0.0.1` avoids sending via IPv6.